# Compute $L_p$ norm of exponential of standard Gaussian

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, lp-spaces, moment-generating-functions

I am trying to compute the $L_p$ norm of $X$ such that $X$ is $e^{Y}$ and $Y$ is the standard Gaussian.

I started with the fact that

$$\|X\|_{Lp} = \left(E\left|e^{Y}\right|^{p}\right)^{1/p}$$

and that

$$E \left(e^{pY}\right) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{pY} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{Y^2}{2}} dy$$

Am I in the correct direction or did I make some mistake defining this integral?

Comment: You are using the integration variable $z$, which apparently is not in the integrand. The integral you are seeking is $(2\pi)^{-1/2}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{py}e^{-y^2/2}dy$.

Comment: That was a typo sorry, I wonder now what would be the integral in the case of $ z= e^{sX}$ and X is the same as above. How can I compute the expectation of z in that case?

Answer (score 2):

You are in the good direction: complete the square to get
$$
-\frac{y^2}2+py=-\frac 12\left(y^2-2py\right)=-\frac 12\left((y-p)^2-p^2\right)
$$
and do the substitution $t=y-p$.

Comment: I suppose I can use $-1/2(y-p)^{2}$ as the power of exponential and now I have the gaussian integral of N(p,1) which can be integrated to 1 and then I have evaluated the integral to $e^{p^{2}/2}$